# How can you control the speed of fan that comes with the Antec Sonata III case from the outside?

Tags: fan

The Antec Sonata III case comes with a nice 120mm fan that has a 3 speed switch.  Most of the time the fan is fine on low, but for games or other taxing workloads I need to switch it to medium or high.  Opening the case every time I want to change the setting is kind of a pain.

Has anyone figured out a way to control the speed from the outside of the case without going nuclear (e.g. cutting holes in the case)?  Other than this annoyance I like the case and the fan that comes with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the usual Antec 3-speed control with a fairly long cable, could you no remove an expansion card slot and poke the switch out the back?

Assumes you have fairly easy access to the back of the case, of course.

Comment: I have relatively easy access to the back.  I'd prefer not eating up a slot, but if no one comes up with anything else I might have to do that.  It's otherwise a great case - I'm surprised Antec didn't provide some obvious cutout (or even better, have a cutout with the switch mounted in it already).

Comment: Aye, I've a couple of Antec cases with their 3-speed fans, and it does seem a missed trick not to have them wired to a panel on either the front or back. Not much of an issue for me as I don't OC and low-speed is fine, but for mid-range enthusiast cases, it seems an obvious omission.

Comment: I don't OC either, but I do have a Quad Core Extreme that runs pretty hot.  I like to keep things quiet, so I have a Ninja Skythe cooler on it running passively (no fan).  Works fine unless I play games longer than about an hour...that's fairly rare, but it does happen.  For the record, I snuck the cable out the expansion slot and since it's relatively flat was able to put the cover back on the slot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the same exact fan, but I've had one with a switch attached to a cable before. What I just did was run the cable through one of the holes on the back of the case (anywhere, doesn't matter, the cable is pretty thin). Then you can switch it by reaching around to the back of the case.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way... Just unscrew that little switch box, pull the switch out from the box and run it through one of those 4 square holes on the side of the elongated fan vent. Then put it back in the box and ... :) I know it's a bit "tight" but... ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this with that software:

http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Comment: No - the fan has a physical switch and power only.  It does not even connect to the fan control header of the motherboard, so software-solutions are out.

Comment: That's what I thought. I guess the only way is to have an outside-casing switch that allows you to change the fan's speed...